# Jenkins groovy process

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently writing a pipeline under Jenkins via a Groovy script.
My problem is that I have to run a long process (minimum 20 min) and I would like to be able to redirect the output of my process to the "Console" of Jenkins job.

This process is a script written in Python and is launched on a remote server via SSH.
I tried to launch my SSH command with the `-tt` argument or to run my script using the : `python3 -u myscript.py` command but without success.

Many answers on the Internet allow to recover the output but never in real time.
One solution seemed perfect: `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`.

Only, it would seem that this works only on a "normal" Groovy script but not on a Jenkins pipeline.

Would you have an idea how I could display the output of my python script in real time?

I thank you in advance !

Comment: Could you test with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin - new Jenkins comes with better error/stdout redirection. (atleast in case of maven builds)